# Unitialized Constant Error in Spec File due to Abstract Class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm quite new to rspec, and when I run the spec file I receive the following error:

```
 An error occurred in a `before(:suite)` hook.
  Failure/Error: DatabaseCleaner[:active_record].db = PairHistoryRecord

   NameError:
    uninitialized constant PairHistoryRecord
   # ./spec/support/database_cleaner.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

which leads me to here in my database_cleaner spec:

```
 config.before(:suite) do
default_db = DatabaseCleaner[:active_record].db
DatabaseCleaner[:active_record].db = PairHistoryRecord
```

So I locate the Pair_History_Record.rb file, but it all looks in order. However, I've noticed it's an abstract class, and I think the error may be related to this. Can someone tell me how best to debug this? Perhaps I'm reading the error wrong?

```
    class PairHistoryRecord < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true
  if Settings.features.switch_to_pair_history_db
    establish_connection :"pair_history_#{Rails.env}"
  else
    establish_connection Rails.env.to_sym
  end
end
```

Comment: `self.abstract_class = true` really has very little to do with abstract classes as you may know it from other languages and most likely has nothing to do with the error. Rather it has to do with how Rails derives the table name from the class name and inheritance. If you comment out `self.abstract_class = true` Rails will assume that any subclasses of PairHistoryRecord are Single Table Inhertiance classes that are stored in the `pair_history_records` table.

Comment: i guess you're using Rails version < 6 or using 6+ with `autoloader :classic`. It looks like Rails is not support file-name convenient `Pair_History_Record.rb` in both cases , you could try to rename the file to `pair_history_record.rb`.